# pattern in regex java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to find position start and end of pattern on my text.

I use following code:

```
Pattern _pat=Pattern.compile("20.  Eslaminejad MB, Nikmahzar A, Piriea A. The structure   of "
+"Human Mesenchymal Stem Cells differentiated into cartilage in micro mass culture   system. Yakhteh 2006, 8(3): "
+"162-171.");

Matcher _match=_pat.matcher("19.  Eslaminejad  MB,  Eftekhari-Yazdi  P.   Mesenchymal  stem "
 +"cells: In vitro differentiation among bone and cartilage cell "
+"lineages. Yakhteh. 2007; 9(3): 158-169."
+"20.  Eslaminejad MB, Nikmahzar A, Piriea A. The structure of "
+"Human Mesenchymal Stem Cells differentiated into cartilage in micro mass culture     system. Yakhteh 2006, 8(3): "
+"162-171."
+"21.  Pioletti  DP,  Montjovent  MO,  Zambelli  PY,  Applegate  L. "
+"Bone tissue engineering using foetal cell therapy. Swiss "
+"Med Wkly. 2006 ; 136(35-36): 557-560.");


    while(_match.find()){
       System.out.println(_match.start());
       System.out.println(_match.end());
    }
```

Unfortunately, the pattern is not finding the string in my text.

Comment: This isn't how you use regex. Please look at this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: In your search string you have more whitespace between words than you do in the text being searched. For example between "structure" and "of"

Comment: use regex only if you can't do it with normal string functions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, what you need is not regex, but just

```
int start = inputString.indexOf(stringToSearch);
```

This will give you the start position and the end position is calculated as

```
int end = start+stringToSearch.length();
```

You may want to normalize whitespace or perform other typical normalization operations before attempting a match.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in different number of spaces. Compare:

```
The structure   of
```

from the pattern with

```
The structure of
```

from the text.

By the way although you are using patterns you do not use any features that patterns provide, so in you case you could use simple `String.contains()` method.